# issue with show image of products in multi website different domains

Tags: magento2, multistore, product-images, store-view

I am using Magento 2.2.3 and have multi-website with different  domains
now it is working fine.
but my problem now is the image of products doesn't show on the second website the products associated correctly to the second website and view store and
showing as info but without the photo ?

[image]

I try to make force re-indexing and flush cache but not solve this issue

Comment: Should check the image path of second website.

Comment: how I can make second website read paths images from main site